# Mac location not found for opened .dmg

Tags: finder, mojave, dmg

I tried downloading `android-studio-ide-181.5056338-mac.dmg` to install it, but double clicking the .dmg does not nothing but put `Android Studio 3.2.1` under the locations sidebar in the Finder. When I click that, I get the error message:
[image]

I tried doing the same for installing `Amazon Photos` and the exact same thing happened.

What's going on with my Mac being unable to open .dmg files?

Mac OS 10.14.1 (18B75)

Comment: Mac is protecting you by hiding the Non Apple apps.

Comment: That's not desired behavior. Have never experienced this before. It should at least give me the option to open anyway, but it literally does nothing and gives theses confusing useless errors.

Comment: You are right. I would say this is a bad behaviour in term of security. The error produced is of no help about the origin of the problem. I suggest you to report this on the Apple feedback server: https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html .

Answer (score 2):

Tell your Mac Gatekeeper, you are the Boss and responsible for your actions and decisions.

Open the Terminal app from the /Applications/Utilities/ folder and then enter the following command syntax:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

Hit return and authenticate with an admin password

That should now allow you to download and install non Apple apps, by selecting it in the System Pref > Security